# Is it possible to have different TDictionary TValue Types

Tags: delphi

I have a question about the TDictionary container in Delphi. I know that the generic TDictionary is TDictionary. Is there a way to include two different types for TValue.

For example, I have some data that I am parsing, and would like to create a TDictionary with TKey type of String, and TValue of Boolean, and Integer. Is this possible, or do all of the TValue types have to be the same?

Comment: The value type can be a common suberclass of the given TValue types - so with the exception of primitive types, it is possible.

Comment: That "exception" can be covered by using Rtti.TValue as the tvalue of the dictionary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a single instance of a TDictionary, all of the TValue types must be the same.

If you need both, you can use a variant record, or even a variant type.

Comment: Or of course the TValue record as defined in the Rtti unit, to avoid using variants.